# How to dockerize spring boot maven app with local dependency

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, maven

I have user-service and util spring boot packages. I have implemented `util -> user-service` as local dependency. It works on my local machine because I have maven m2 repo and running `mvn clean package deploy` command for `util`. However if someone clones the project who does not have maven, and try to run it on docker how will it build? How many Dockerfile do I need and also how can I create a docker-compose.yml file to run everything with just `docker compose up -d` command?

- util service

```
  ..........
    <artifactId>util</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>util</name>
    <description>util</description>
   .........
 <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>util</id>
            <name>util</name>
            <url>file://${project.build.directory}/local-maven-repo</url>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>
```

- user-service

```
      <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gucardev</groupId>
            <artifactId>util</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Well, thats why your docker image should have all the necessary dependencies. Like a uber jar for example.

Comment: Everybody can publish on maven central https://maven.apache.org/repository/guide-central-repository-upload.html .

Comment: Like what the previous comments mentioned, similar concept of a common remote code repository (ex: github), then there should also be a common remote repository for your dependencies (ex: maven central).

Answer (score 0):

There is a contradiction in the question. You say: "However if someone clones the project who does not have maven, and try to run it on docker how will it build"
If someone clones the project one way or another this project must be compiled (with maven in your case). Otherwise having a source code doesn't make sense.
Docker is used to run the project, spring boot also is used during runtime, but how can you compile the project if you don't have its dependencies available?

I suggest you to address this issue separately from other raised points. Basically you have the following choices:

1. Add utils module (source code) next to your main application module in maven , when you compile you'll compile both utils and the application modules together.
2. Distribute the Utils module separately (for example if it's supposed to be consumed as a dependency by several projects). Put it into your nexus / artifactory repository whatever your company uses.
3. Place Utils module into a separate repository and update the build procedure: It must include checking out / compiling the utils module and then compiling your application.

Now when maven finishes the compilation you can have a spring boot application represented by one big jar and all actual dependencies will reside inside the jar (BOOT-INF/lib folder to be precise).

This compiled and packaged jar (the straightforward approach is using spring boot maven plugin - it will prepare a jar for you) should include all the dependencies (among them the utils of course).

Then the docker is just need to run `java -jar <your-app-jar>` so the depdency issue is out of scope at this time...